# Algorithm to convert DN values to Radiance

Tags: algorithm

Which algorithm should I use to convert DN(Digital Number) values to radiance. There are many different algorithm that I found, there are 3 for now (based on youtube, article, usgs website).

My aim is to extract LST from Band 10 of Landsat 8 OLI/TIRS.

Below are the list of formula that I found:

1. [image: List item]
2. [image: List item]
3. [image: List item]

This are the results of min max value for each algorithm:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Equations 1 and 3 are the same with different notation (result could slightly differ because of rounding). They both use Oi which should not be considered anymore since February 2014. So you could use equation 2 if your data is more recent than February 2014. Note that the main source of uncertainty in LST is the emissivity: L is the "at sensor radiance" and not the radiance of a supposed blackbody surface target.

As far as I know, the study of reference on Landsat thermal band 10 is Tardy et al (2016) https://www.mdpi.com/2072-4292/8/9/696

Answer (score 0):

The values ​​are all relatively similar and only differ from the second decimal place and I think that it doesn't have to be more precise for LST. When in doubt, I would use the formula from the USGS website, or the one used in most scientific studies.

Answer (score 0):

Oi represents the offsets supplied by USGS for the TIRS band calibration and since February 2014, they are out of consideration.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this official USGS guide to convert the data: https://www.usgs.gov/core-science-systems/nli/landsat/using-usgs-landsat-level-1-data-product